# what are options for automated unit testing in angular js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

I'm new for unit testing so i want to know best automated option for angular js app testing.

I found some framework call Jasmine and Karma but I want to know best option.

Comment: `I found some framework call Jasmine and Karma but I want to know best option` : I thought, This is the best option .

Comment: do you have any idea about other option available for testing

Comment: another one is -  http://www.protractortest.org/#/  
But karma is a best framework for UI testing

Comment: Protractor is best for e2e testing, for unit it's really whatever you fancy, jasmine, karma, mocha, probably jest for angular2

Comment: Karma is the test runner that Google built to do unit testing of Angular (made by Google), which runs Jasmine tests.  Protractor (also made by Google) is meant for e2e testing.  So it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.